# Not able to append HTML code in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, append

I am not able to append my HTML code using jQuery.
This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="am-right-section">
    <div class="right-quote-section">
    <img class="customer-profile-img" src="http://45.56.70.30/mijpaal_am/pub/media/images/avtaaar.png" width="100px" height="100px"><div class="centered">
    <div id="loading" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://45.56.70.30/mijpaal_am/pub/media/am-loader/loader.gif">
    </div>
    </div>
<form class="form customerdetail" action="http://45.56.70.30/mijpaal_am/accountmanager/accountmanager/amsave" id="customerdetail" method="post" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">

                <div class="control">
                    <input name="customer_land" id="customer_land" class="customer_land required-entry1" aria-required="true" type="text">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="action submit primary">
                    <span>Generate Request</span>
                </button>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">kndsa jkasf kajf kndsa jkasf kajf  kndsa jkasf kajf  kndsa jkasf kajf  kndsa jkasf kajf  kndsa jkasf kajf  </div>

        </div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
<script>
 jQuery('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        jQuery(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a><span>x</span></li>');         
        jQuery('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'"><?php echo $template;?></div>');
});
</script>
```

I have set my HTML in $template variable successfully.But append does not works.my html does not append into the tab-content class.

Please solve my query.Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: No element with 'tab-content' as class exists.

Comment: I have not post entire HTML.But tab-content class is exist.

Comment: I think you better post it so we can test fully enough.

Comment: please see my edited question now.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar first try to **append** simple markup without the $template. To rule out any problem that may be caused by $template

Comment: @Benny, If i put any simple text then it works fine. All issue might be happening due to html. Is there any issue related to the single or double quote?

Comment: @B.Desai, Yes , i got error in console like , "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"

Comment: show output of `$template`

Comment: forgot everything , can you append this html.     <div class="quote-status">
  <input name="quote-status-value" value="0" checked="" type="radio"> Get Email and set value<br>
  <input name="quote-status-value" value="1" type="radio"> Set value<br>
</div>

Comment: **id** or $template are the issue. console.log them both

Answer (score 1):

Tested with the below. It works. Must be a problem with the content of $template.

```
<?php
        $template =<<<JS
        <div class="quote-status"> <input name="quote-status-value" value="0" checked="" type="radio"> Get Email and set value<br> <input name="quote-status-value" value="1" type="radio"> Set value<br> </div>
JS;
        ?>      
        <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        jQuery(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a><span>x</span></li>');   
        jQuery('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'"><?php echo $template;?></div>');
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: can i put php variable between <<<JS and JS?

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure the last JS; has no indentation.

Comment: can you please send me with example? how to put the variable between  that?

Comment: Just a simple $variable. If it's an array then do {$variable[0]} or {$variable['key']}

Answer (score 1):

I think, your jQuery code is running before page load. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(".nav-tabs").children().length;
        jQuery(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a><span>x</span></li>');         
        jQuery('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'"><?php echo $template;?></div>');
    });
});
```